# Weird multiplication result

Tags: arduino-uno

Here's come Arduino code.

```
#define M(x, y) x * y;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println(M(3 + 2, 4 + 2));
}
void loop() {
}
```

Why is the result 13?

Answer (score 16):

Because `M(3 + 2, 4 + 2)` gets replaced to `3 + 2 * 4 + 2` and then the normal priority of operations does the multiply before the addition.

This is one of the many reasons why you should prefer functions over macros. The inliner of the compiler will negate any call overhead.

If you truly want to use a macro then surround each use of the macro arguments in parenthesis, surround the macro itself in parenthesis as well.

```
#define M(x, y) ((x) * (y))
```

Comment: Always also surround the whole macro in parenthesis; otherwise you can have the same problem in the other direction: If you do `#define A(x, y) (x) + (y)`, then `A(1, 2) * 3` will expand to `(1) + (2) * 3` = 7, instead of `((1) + (2)) * 3` = 9, like one would expect.

Comment: And trailing semicolon here will also make problems.